# Soccer slide tackle

Tags: football

A player is onto goal, he dribbles pass a defender and shoots but the defender slides him and he misses the goal. What should the referee do:

1. If it was in the penalty area?
2. If it was outside?

Comment: The ball is out when he receives the foul or is still on the field?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem particularly complicated:

1. The referee determines if the contact was a foul or not. Obviously if it was a legal challenge, play continues or is restarted based on where the ball left the playing area and who contacted it last.
2. Assuming it was a foul, the referee awards a direct free kick (if the offence occurred outside the penalty area) or a penalty (if inside).
3. The referee determines if the offending player should be cautioned or sent off (or neither), based on the characteristics of the offence, including whether it was a denial of an obvious goalscoring opportunity or not.

I'm guessing your question is about whether the process should somehow be different based on where the challenge occurs, to which the answer is always "no".